# How to fetch existing cache data on every input change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form, react-query

My application has a user `input` an `id` to send as a `request` and the `response data` that matches that `id` is rendered.

If the `data` already exist in the `cache`, I'd like the application to fetch from the `cache` on each `input change`.

If the `data` does not exist in the `cache`, the application can only send the `request` by having the user click the `submit button`.

Once a user types in the `input`, I would access `cache` and check if the current input `id` exists on every `input change`. If so, render the `data` while the `submit button` is `disabled`. Else `enable` the `submit button` so that the user can send the `request`.

From research, [React Query's queryClient.getQueryCache](https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/QueryClient#queryclientgetquerycache) is what I believe I need. I would check to see if the input `id` exists in the `cache` by using `.includes` on `queryCache`. What would I do afterwards? Is this the correct direction to implement the functionality?

Here is my current setup. Please let me know how to move forward implementing the requested functionality. https://codesandbox.io/s/rick-and-morty-2gy8r?file=/src/App.js

```
const handleRickAndMortyFetch = () => {
  return delay()
    .then(() => axios(`https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/${idQuery}`))
    .then((res) => res.data);
  };

const cacheData = queryClient.getQueryData(["rickandmorty", idQuery], {
    exact: false
})

const onInputChange = event => {
    setIdQuery(event.target.value, () => {
        cacheData.includes(idQuery)
            handleRickAndMortyFetch()
    })
}

const disable = isLoading || parseFloat(formId) === idQuery || !idQuery || cacheData?.id === idQuery;

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
  <input
    type="number"
    name="rickAndMortyId"
    placeholder="Between 1 and 671"
    ref={register}
    disabled={isLoading}
    onChange={onInputChange}
  />
  <button type="submit" disabled={disable}>
    Search Character
  </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want is `queryClient.getQueryData(["rickandmorty", idQuery])`. This will give you data from the cache for a specific queryKey. If that is `undefined`, you have no data in the cache for that key, so you can enable the submit button.

But you need to let react-query manage the data for you please. That means your `handleRickAndMortyFetch` function should *return* a Promise - there is no need to use local state (`rickAndMortyCharacter`) - this is just the `data` property returned from react-query

Comment: Thank you, now the app on every input change will fetch if input value is nonexistent in cache and only access from cache if input value exists within. However, how do I disable the submit button if input value exist in cache. I have `disable` defined as `const disable = isLoading || parseFloat(formId) === idQuery || cacheData.name === idQuery`. But I receive a `TypeError: Cannot read property name of undefined.` Please take a look at the updated code.

Comment: Well as I said, the data in the cache _can_ be undefined if it doesn’t exist, so I’d use optional chaining: `cacheData?.name === idQuery`

Comment: Thank you for your help for the fetch-on-every-input-change logic! Sorry, the `cacheData.` and `cacheData?.` wasn't working. I'll continue researching to have the disabling logic figured out. 